# In R, conditionally remove duplicate rows within ID, Date, and Event

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data.table

**Background**

I have `d`, a dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a", "b","b"),
                event = c("G12","G12","O99","O99","B4","B2"),
                date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2011-01-01","2011-12-23","2011-12-23","2011-01-01","2011-07-12")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

As you can see, ID `a` has 4 rows, 2 of which are repeats based on `event` and `date` (rows 2 and 4 are the duplicates).

**The Problem and Desired Output**

I'd like to remove these duplicate rows by asking `R` to remove rows within `ID` that have the same `event` and `date`. In other words, I'd like something that looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a", "b","b"),
                event = c("G12","O99","B4","B2"),
                date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2011-12-23", "2011-01-01","2011-07-12")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**What I've tried**

I've made an attempt but it's not quite there:

```
d2 <- subset(d, duplicated(d$ID, d$event))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need `d[!duplicated(d[1:2]),]`,  `duplicated` - `x` is a single parameter.  If you need to specify as separate, use `d %>% distinct(ID, event, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: I have a call for an hour right now but I'll try this as soon as I get back to my desk. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [unique](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/unique)

```r
unique(d)
#>   ID event       date
#> 1  a   G12 2011-01-01
#> 3  a   O99 2011-12-23
#> 5  b    B4 2011-01-01
#> 6  b    B2 2011-07-12
```

Using [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf)

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(d)

unique(dt[, .(event, date), by = ID])
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>